# Best way to use datas between server and angular client?

Tags: asp.net, json, angularjs, web, web-applications

We are developing a web application using C# and Angular.

The client and the server communicate with JSON to send datas.

My problem as a fronted developer is : When they change the model's variable's name, the client doesn't still work anymore.

Example :
if the model is:

```
public class Person 
{
   public string name;
}
```

In the Angular Application I use exaclty the same structure when I receive the JSON:

```
<h1>{{myJson.name}}</h1>
```

And sometimes the back-end developers change the variable's name, I need to return to update the client side, and I loose big time in debugging with that.

Any tutorial or blog or something to know what's the best way to use data between server and client ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the external shape/behavior of code changes, then any code which uses it must also change.  This is the definition of a "breaking change".

I suspect the ideal way to avoid this problem is to have a set of automated tests which validate the code.  If someone makes a breaking change, tests will fail.  At that point the build is considered "broken".

If possible, it may be worth implementing a kind of "check-in rejection" system where the source control doesn't allow a check-in of a build which fails to compile or fails tests.  This is native functionality in TFS, but may not be a feasible option for many systems.

Failing that as a technical barrier, at that point it's pretty much a team-enforced barrier.  Someone breaks the build, they are responsible for fixing it.  Sure, sometimes that person has left for the day or maybe there's some other reason why you or another team member needs to "clean up after them", but it should be clear from the source control history that *they* broke the build.

If you're spending a lot of time fixing things which other developers broke, that's less of a technical problem and more of a team dynamics problem.  Automated tests bring visibility to that problem.  Developers shouldn't be able to check in code with failing tests, either through a technical barrier or a social one.

Comment: Thank you, testing and comminication are the keys ...